# R - correct way to specify a logistic regression with fixed effects?

Tags: r, binary, logistic-regression

Say I have data on million passes in US basketball games. The data looks like this made-up example:

```
data <- data.frame(same_team = c(0,0,1,0,1,0),
               length_pass= c(1,2,5,7,1,3),
               year= c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
               mean_length_pass_team= c(15,15,9,14,14,8),
               team= c('A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'))

data
  same_team length_pass year mean_length_pass_team team
1         0           1    1                    15    A
2         0           2    1                    15    A
3         1           5    1                     9    B
4         0           7    2                    14    A
5         1           1    2                    14    A
6         0           3    2                     8    B
```

Each observation is a pass from a player on team X to another player. The dependent variable records whether the pass is completed between players on the same team (0/1).

I want to estimate the impact of `length_pass` on `same_team` passes, controlling for `year` and `mean_length_pass_team`. I also want to control for `team` fixed effects.

**Is the following model specification for a logit regression with fixed effects correct?**

I'm especially unsure if the team fixed effects are correctly specified.

```
library(bife)
bife(same_team ~ length_pass + year + mean_length_pass_team | team, data=data)

library(survival)
clogit(same_team ~ length_pass + year + mean_length_pass_team + strata(team), data=data)
```

Comment: The bife syntax seems correct. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bife/vignettes/bife_introduction.html. Can't comment on the survival approach.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth looking at the full model (I don't think you need `mean_length_pass_team`),

```
m1 <- glm(same_team ~ year * length_pass * team, data = data, family = binomial)
summary(m1)
```

and see if you get significant interactions? Since you wanted to control for `mean_length_pass_team`, which is a function of `length_pass`, `team`, and `year`, I would say you are implicitly expecting them.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned with specifying the fixed effects correctly. I want to control for team fixed effects because there might be other, unobserved, variations at the team level.

Answer (score -1):

Using base R *glm* function, you can specify fixed effects thus:

```
glm(same_team ~ length_pass + year + mean_length_pass_team +factor(team), family=binomial, data=data)
```